# How to fill a list of Tuple whose number of elements is determined by a variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to fill a list of Tuple where the number of elements is determined by an Enumerable.
I tried to loop through the enumerable within the Tuple list:

```
    var items = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Table>().Where(x => tableIds.Contains(x.Id));

    var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>> {

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                new Tuple<string, string>(item.A1, item.A2),
                new Tuple<string, string>(item.A1, item.A2)
            {
    };
```

But this  does not seem to be allowed (-> red wiggling lines at the closing curly brackets)).
Looping through from outside the Tuple list does not expose the Tuple list for further use.
Any help would be appreciated. Regards, Manu

With Tims suggestion my code looks now:

```
    public IEnumerable<EmailListModel> Get()
    {
        IIndireKatPrincipal indireKatPrincipal = identityStorage.GetPrincipal();
        var groupId = indireKatPrincipal.GroupId;
        var araIds = UnitOfWork.GetAll<UserGroup>()
                .Where(group => group.Id == groupId)
                .SelectMany(group => group.S_ARA).Select(ara => ara.Id);

        var aras = UnitOfWork.GetAll<S_ARA>().Where(x => araIds.Contains(x.Id)).AsEnumerable();

        List<Tuple<string, string>> tupleList = aras
            .Select(ara => new Tuple<string, string>(ara.IEVName, ara.IEVEmail))
            .ToList();

        var emailListModel = tupleList.Select(entity => new EmailListModel()
        {
            DisplayAddress = entity.Item1,
            EmailAddress = entity.Item2
        }).ToList();

        return emailListModel;
    }
```

And it works perfect now (after adding .AsEnumerable() at var aras = ...).

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this part of the code? I cannot observe the same behavior you describe in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6CEYRK)

Comment: @Icepickle: I tried it also with another Enumerable of which I am sure that it yields proper records -> same error in debug-mode -> NotSupportedException, in LINQ to Entities only parameter-free constructors/initializers are supported

Comment: I guess this information is missing from your question, however I fail to see what it has to do with the line you have mentioned that is errourness

Comment: @Icepickle: Now I tried it with your ItemDataSource and did not get an error. So there must be an error somewhere in my ItemDataSource (var aras = ...). I will work on that.

Comment: @Icepickle: I found the problem. I had to append .AsEnumerable() to my ItemDataSource (var aras = ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `foreach` in  a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). Use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> tupleList = items
   .Select(item => new Tuple<string, string>(item.A1, item.A2))
   .ToList();
```

> [Collection initializer:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)
>   The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an
>   object initializer

An [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions) is allowed but not a [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements)(f.e. a loop)

Comment: You can simplify the Select a little to:  `.Select(item => Tuple.Create(item.A1, item.A2))`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: i have adapted OP's preferences to create a tuple using the constructor

Comment: Indeed, but perhaps the OP didn't know about `Tuple.Create()` so it's good to let him know about it!

Comment: @MatthewWatson: normally i also try to suggest better approaches but in this case it's just a matter of personal preference. There is no difference in using the constructor or the factory method apart from few letters more or less. Maybe he likes that the type is not derived from the arguments but visible in the code. If i start to suggest so minor things(which also distract from the core issue of his question), then i had to write novels in every answer ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I used your suggestion -> no compile errors, but runtime-error (only parameter-free constructors/initializers supported). Now I am stuck.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: it gives back an empty list because of the runtime-error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C#7 you can use the new Tuple syntax to do this:

```
var tupleList = items.Select(item => (item.A1, item.A2)).ToList();

...

foreach (var item in tupleList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item2);
}
```

If you want, you can change the name of the properties from the default `Item1` and `Item2` to something else:

```
var tupleList = items.Select(item => (A1: item.A1, A2: item.A2)).ToList();

foreach (var item in tupleList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.A1);
    Console.WriteLine(item.A2);
}
```